# Implementing LocalStorage into an authentication form in express and ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, local-storage

I am making a authentication form were users can register and login.

```
if (process.env.Node_ENV !== 'production') {
    require('dotenv').config()
}

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const passport = require("passport")
const flash = require("express-flash")
const sessions = require("express-session")
const methodOverride = require("method-override")
const fs = require('fs')


const initializePassport = require("./passport-config")
initializePassport(
    passport, 
    email => users.find(user => user.email === email),
    id => users.find(user => user.id === id)
)

const users = []

app.set("view-engine", "ejs")
app.use('/public', express.static('public'))

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.use(flash())

app.use(sessions({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))

app.get("/", checkAuthenticated, (req,res)=> {
    res.render("index.ejs", { name: req.user.name})
})

app.get("/login", checkNotAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.render("login.ejs")
})

app.post("/login", checkNotAuthenticated,  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: "/",
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true
}))


app.get("/register", checkNotAuthenticated, (req,res)=> {
    res.render("register.ejs")
})

app.post("/register", checkNotAuthenticated, async (req,res) => {
    try{
        //encrypt the Uses password, so "we" cant see it
        const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
        users.push({
            id: Date.now().toString(),
            name: req.body.name,
            email: req.body.email,
            password: hashedPassword
        })
        //if all the above is right, than redirect the user to login page
        res.redirect("/login")
    }catch{
        //if for some reason there is a failure, redirect back to register
        res.redirect("/register")
    }
    //if there is user that is added, it is possible to see ind the console
    //console.log(users)
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(users));
})

app.delete('/logout', (req,res) => {
    req.logOut()
    res.redirect('/login')
})

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    }
    res.redirect('/login')
}

function checkNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.redirect('/')
    }
    next()
}
```

The problem is that I need to implement localStorage, and the user needs to be able to delete the account once they are logged in.

To register the user only needs "Name", "email" and "password"

here is some of my passport-config if necessary:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt")



function initialize(passport, getUserByEmail, getUserById){
    const authenticateUser = async (email, password, done) => {
        const user = getUserByEmail(email)
        if (user == null) {
            return done(null, false, {message: "No user with that Email"})
        }

        try{
            if(await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)) {
                return done(null, user)
            } else{
                return done(null, false, {message: "Passwrod incorrect"})
            }
        }catch(error){
            return done(error)
        }
    } 
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'}, authenticateUser))
    passport.serializeUser((user,done) => done(null, user.id))
    passport.deserializeUser((id,done) => {
       return done(null, getUserById(id))
    })

}

module.exports = initialize;
```

Everything works fine, so there is no error in the code it's self, I just don't seem to find an answer to what I need to do anywhere, I can only find mongoDB which I don't want to use. The most important for me is to implement the localStorage, then it comes the delete part.

I hope some of you can help me!

Thanks a lot.